# How to compare time with correct PDT?

Tags: java, calendar

I want to compare the time as below, the two result time values are created by Calendar with setting timezone to "PST". When I compare the two times, the result is always wrong.

Log time: Tue Oct 06 17:21:17 PDT 1970, while action time: Mon Oct 06 17:49:47 PDT 2014

Code is like below:

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS");
df.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("PST"));
s = newLine.substring(0, 17);
calendar.setTime(df.parse(s));
```

Comment: So...where are you getting this mystical value `s` from? What does it contain?

Comment: It is like "09-22 16:34:45.808"

Comment: It doesn't have a year attached, so it'd kind of make sense that it would default back to the UNIX epoch.

Answer (score -2):

I do not see any compare in your code snippet, thus can't really comment on the code. You should read this on stackoverflow,

<[How to compare Calendar's time to java.sql.Time object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8771587/how-to-compare-calendars-time-to-java-sql-time-object)>[Read This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8771587/how-to-compare-calendars-time-to-java-sql-time-object)

See Lion (2nd response in the thread), it basically explains everything, or you can just read the Java docs.

Comment: this does not answer the question, and is more suitable as a comment.