# H2 set default time zone

Tags: java, hibernate, timezone, h2

How can I set the time zone of H2 database?
I'm using Hibernate for creating the database.

Comment: I can't tell you and even if I could, it wouldn't help you, because the time zone of the database doesn't matter for storing Date values. It is the time zone of the client which matters. Pls. see my answer on your other question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**EDIT**: I found out my answer is probably incorrect, misleading at the very least. I tried to delete it, but apparently it is not possible.

Please see instead: [How to store date/time and timestamps in UTC time zone with JPA and Hibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/508019/jpa-hibernate-store-date-in-utc-time-zone?rq=1)