# How to set the TimeZone for String parsing in Android

Tags: java, android, timezone

I try to parse a String and set a time zone, but I can't produce the desired result.

```
String dtc = "2014-04-02T07:59:02.111Z";
SimpleDateFormat readDate = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'");
Date date = null;
try {
   date = readDate.parse(dtc);
   Log.d("myLog", "date "+date);
} catch (ParseException e) {
   Log.d("myLog", "dateExcep " + e);
}

SimpleDateFormat writeDate = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy, HH.mm"); 
writeDate.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT+04:00"));
String dateString = writeDate.format(date);
```

At the output of the variable "dateString" still gives the time 07:59:02 , and I want to make it +4 hours in advance that is 11:59:02

Comment: SimpleDateFormat(String template, Locale locale)
or setTimeZone(TimeZone timezone)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/508019/jpa-hibernate-store-date-in-utc-time-zone

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You need to instruct the read-formatter to interprete the input as UTC (GMT - remember that Z stands for UTC in ISO-8601-format):

```
String dtc = "2014-04-02T07:59:02.111Z";
SimpleDateFormat readDate = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'");
readDate.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT")); // missing line
Date date = readDate.parse(dtc);
SimpleDateFormat writeDate = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy, HH.mm");
writeDate.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT+04:00"));
String s = writeDate.format(date);
```

Then you will get:

02.04.2014, 11.59

Comment: Thank you very much for the missing line.

Answer (score 3):

## Joda-Time

Doing date-time work much easier and simpler with the [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) library than with the notoriously troublesome bundled java.util.Date & .Calendar classes.

## Time Zone

Using [proper time zone names](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones), rather than a specific offset, is generally a wiser approach.

## Example Code

Here is some example code using Joda-Time 2.3.

Notice:

- Joda-Time has built-in parsers for strings in [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format. No need to instantiate parsing or formatting objects.
- Joda-Time is both parsing the UTC string *and* adjusting it to another time zone all in one call to the [`DateTime`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html) constructor.
- When converting to a UTC-based dateTime in the last line, we still have the same moment in the timeline of the Universe (same count of milliseconds since [Unix epoch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time)).

Source…

```
String input = "2014-04-02T07:59:02.111Z";
DateTimeZone timeZone = DateTimeZone.forID( "Asia/Dubai" );
DateTime dateTimeDubai = new DateTime( input, timeZone ); (a) Parse, (b) Adjust time zone.
DateTime dateTimeUtc = dateTimeDubai.withZone( DateTimeZone.UTC );
```

Dump to console…

```
System.out.println( "input: " + input );
System.out.println( "dateTimeDubai: " + dateTimeDubai );
System.out.println( "dateTimeUtc: " + dateTimeUtc );
```

When run…

```
input: 2014-04-02T07:59:02.111Z
dateTimeDubai: 2014-04-02T11:59:02.111+04:00
dateTimeUtc: 2014-04-02T07:59:02.111Z
```

Answer (score 0):

you can take whatever pattern you want like i have date+ time zone. so you can set according to you.  here is my code.

```
 SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
```

here i have set the date format.

```
String currentDate = dateFormat.format(currentLocalTime);
 String localTime = date.format(currentLocalTime);// to get the time zone i have used this.
  String newtime=currentDate+localTime;// and then i have apeend this now print log you will get the desire result.
```