# Set Time Zone in Android App on the basis of server response

Tags: android, customization, gmt

I am doing some work which scenario is 
, I am receiving date and time from server as a data field.
i.e **2016-12-20T16:22:00+05:00**.
I have an spinner in which

*

- (+12:00 to -12:00) values by each hour

*
Now, i need to transform this date & time with respect to spinner value.
i.e if spinner has selected +12:00
then it will like this
**2016-12-21T04:22:00+12:00**.
Please suggest solutions.
Thank you :)

Comment: Your question is not clear. Plz elaborate properly

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22814263/how-set-timezone-in-android Refer this :)

Comment: do you want to increase the time by 12 hours if user has selected +12:00

Comment: Yes, and if addition of +12 make time 24+ then date should be change as well.

Comment: in which format and Locale you are getting your time from server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using Java String Functions like below

```
String time="2016-12-20T16:22:00+05:00";
String[] s =time.split("'+'");
String time1=s[0];


    String value=value from spinner;
    SimpleDateFormat readDate = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss");
    readDate.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT")); // missing line
    Date date = null;
    try {
        date = readDate.parse(time1);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    SimpleDateFormat writeDate = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy, HH.mm.ss");
    writeDate.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT+"+value));
//final time string    
String s1 = writeDate.format(date);
```

Comment: Dear Rajesh, your solution is partially right but sets only GMT time,
i need to change date as well as if addition of time crossed the number 24.
then i need to take care about change of year and month as well.
i.e if i got time from server(2016-12-31T22:22:22+05:00) and my select GMT is +12:00
then it would be like this
2017-1-1T05:22:22+12:00
Please note difference date as well

Comment: I understand what u need.check out the new code above!

Comment: your solution is right :)
Bit error correction use '+' inside commas and use String s1.

Comment: Ok..Mark it as Right Answer so that it will help Other peoples.

Answer (score 0):

Try this method

```
public String convertTimeZone(String date, String timeZone) throws ParseException {
    StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer(date);
    date = buffer.reverse().toString().replaceFirst(":","");
    date = new StringBuffer(date).reverse().toString();
    SimpleDateFormat inFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ");
    inFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT" + timeZone));
    Date toConvert = inFormat.parse(date);
    date = inFormat.format(toConvert);
    return new StringBuffer(date).insert(date.length()-2, ":").toString();
}
```