# Hibernate DST Date mapping issue for timestamps without time zone

Tags: sql, spring, hibernate, postgresql, jpa

I've a problem with storing **java.util/sql.Date** in PostgreSQL using hibernate: I'm storing dates as **timestamp without time zone** type. Now, in most cases everything is alright, as I'm mapping it in entities as **java.util(sql).Date**.

However, I encountered one problem I don't know how to overcome yet:
On March 30th there was a time change (**Daylight Saving Time** started). In my country it meant switching from local **2am** to local **3am**.

In my database I have few entries with times **between** 2 and 3 am, such as

> "2014-03-30 02:15:55"

Now, what Java does is it takes this date and displays it as 3:15:55 am, because of the time change. However, I desperately need it to be 02:15:55, exactly how it's stored in the database (basically meaning don't use the +02:00 timezone **BEFORE** 3am, but use it **AFTER**). I'm afraid about 26th October as well, that's when the DST ends.

Is this possible using Hibernate and/or Spring? I'd love a global config for such case.

Best,
Marcin

Answer (score 1):

You need to store dates in UTC timezone to ignore DST. See this question [How to store date/time and timestamps in UTC time zone with JPA and Hibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/508019/jpa-hibernate-store-date-in-utc-time-zone) for solutions