# Importance of implementing VersionType,LiteralType for custom hibernate Type

Tags: java, hibernate, datetime, timezone

I implemented custom UtcTimestampType in hibernate to always save time in UTC.like discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16955113/1121659). In this post it was suggested that all the over ridden methods are delegated to TimeStampType. I am not sure of role these methods play, is it ok to delegate to TimeStampType? What is the importance of over-riding below methods , correctly:

```
1 . String[] getRegistrationKeys() in org.hibernate.type.BaseType
2.  seed, next, getComparator in org.hibernate.type.VersionType<T>
3.  objectToSQLString in org.hibernate.type.LiteralType
```