# Spring jpa hibernate mysql LocalDate off one day after persist

Tags: mysql, hibernate, jpa, jdbc, localdate

Whenever I persist LocalDate to MySQL Database, the Date is stored one day off (11 Nov 2017 becomes 10 Nov 2017). I've already tried to set the timezone in the application on MySQL server and set the legacyDateTimeCode to false but the problem still exists. Any idea on how to fix it? If I switch to local h2 Database, the Date is stored correctly.

Spring-boot-starter-parent: 1.5.7
hibernate 5.2.10
mysql: 5.7
LocalDate stored in DATE field

Comment: When retrieved via JPA, the value is correct or still off?

Comment: its off in db and in the application thats why i am curious. I thought it might be because of different timezone settings thats why i set them the same on mysql server and in the application. But even then its off.

Comment: Hm... timezone of the actual machine (OS) on which it is running? I remember having this issue couple years back, unfortunately dont remember the details anymore.

Comment: UTC both mysql and applicationserver

Comment: Does [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40438746/2144390) help any?

Comment: No i tried that as well but thank you

Comment: I'm having the same issue. Did you find a fix for it ? Thanks

Comment: i forgot about this. I had this issue again later in another project and it was due to the docker image i created having different time settings that the host. So make sure Host,docker images, and applications do have the same time settings

Comment: https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=85570

Comment: Possibly related: https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=93444

Comment: Having the same problem even with the following configurations:
application properties:
1) spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://xxxx/database?serverTimezone=UTC
2) spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.time_zone=UTC
Spring main class:
    @PostConstruct
    void started() {
        TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
    }
Spring Boot 2.5.8 (w/ hibernate 5.4.33 and mysql connector 8.0.27) and MySQL 8.0

Answer (score 1):

Add spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.time_zone : UTC  In Properties file

Answer (score 1):

I have the following environment:

- Spring-Boot (v3.0.6)
- Spring (v6.0.8)
- Spring-Data (v3.0.5)
- Hibernate (v6.1.7.Final)
- MySQL Connector J (v8.0.33)

I saved a `LocalDate` in UTC timezone without any problems, but if I wanted to read the `LocalDate` from the database it always shifted one day off (my machine TimeZone is `Europe/Berlin`).
Maybe someone has the opposite problem, so that their `LocalDate` is shifted one day on.

Most of the previous answers couldn't really help me. The only solution, which I did not want to use, because it was impractical, was the following start parameter `-Duser.timezone=UTC`.

#### 1. Change `TimeZone.getDefault()`

I tried to change the default `TimeZone` via a simple `@PostConstruct` method in Spring-Boot in my `@SpringBootApplication`.

```java
@PostConstruct
public void changeTimezone() {
  TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
}
```

Still one day off.

#### 2. `TimeZone` in MySQL Connection String

I tried to set the `serverTimezone` via mysql connection string with the following parameter:

`jdbc:mysql://{host}/{database}?serverTimezone=UTC`

Still one day off.

#### 3. Tell Hibernate the `TimeZone`

Next thing is to tell hibernate which `TimeZone` I wanted to use. I've done that via hibernate properties and passed them into my `LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean` instead of setting them into my `application.properties`.

`spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.time_zone=UTC`

Surprise... Still one day off..

(Note: I also added the `TimeZoneStorageType.NORMALIZE_UTC` of hibernate 6, but it shouldn't effect the `LocalDate` java or `java.sql.Date` type.)

`spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.timezone.default_storage=NORMALIZE_UTC`

(HIBERNATE 6 ONLY)

#### 4. Create debug hibernate type and check whats going on.

I debugged through a custom created hibernate descriptor type for `LocalDate`. It quickly became clear that hibernate was doing everything
right and the "error" must lie deeper. So I jumped into mysql-connector-j source code.

The implementation of `java.sql.ResultSet` [`ResultSetImpl`](https://github.com/mysql/mysql-connector-j/blob/dd61577595edad45c398af508cf91ad26fc4144f/src/main/user-impl/java/com/mysql/cj/jdbc/result/ResultSetImpl.java) in the mysql-connector-j is parsing the `java.sql.Date` values with the `TimeZone` of the [`NativeServerSession`](https://github.com/mysql/mysql-connector-j/blob/dd61577595edad45c398af508cf91ad26fc4144f/src/main/protocol-impl/java/com/mysql/cj/protocol/a/NativeServerSession.java).

[See this method in `ResultSetImpl`](https://github.com/mysql/mysql-connector-j/blob/dd61577595edad45c398af508cf91ad26fc4144f/src/main/user-impl/java/com/mysql/cj/jdbc/result/ResultSetImpl.java#L789)

It uses the `ServerSession#getDefaultTimeZone()` method to retrieve the "wanted" `TimeZone`.

[See the `getDefaultTimeZone()` method](https://github.com/mysql/mysql-connector-j/blob/dd61577595edad45c398af508cf91ad26fc4144f/src/main/protocol-impl/java/com/mysql/cj/protocol/a/NativeServerSession.java#L367)

As you can see, it checks if it should return the "cached" [`TimeZone defaultTimeZone`](https://github.com/mysql/mysql-connector-j/blob/dd61577595edad45c398af508cf91ad26fc4144f/src/main/protocol-impl/java/com/mysql/cj/protocol/a/NativeServerSession.java#L102) field.
If not, it recalls the `TimeZone.getDefault()` method.

Now the problem with Spring-Boot is, that the `ServerSession` object is already constructed and has cached the previous `TimeZone.getDefault()` (default jvm `TimeZone`) in the field linked above, before you can change the `TimeZone` in a `@PostConstruct` method via Spring like I've tried.

To fix the issue you can just add these parameters to the mysql connection string:

- `serverTimezone=UTC` - Sets the `TimeZone`
- `useLegacyDatetimeCode=false` - Disables the usage of legacy datetime codes
- `forceConnectionTimeZoneToSession=true` - Forces the `serverTimezone` parameter to the session
- `cacheDefaultTimezone=false` - Disables the caching `TimeZone` problem with spring-boot

Example connection string:

`jdbc:mysql://{host}/{database}?serverTimezone=UTC&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&forceConnectionTimeZoneToSession=true&cacheDefaultTimezone=false`

I could not find any documentation for some parameters, so I link here again to the [`PropertyKey`](https://github.com/mysql/mysql-connector-j/blob/dd61577595edad45c398af508cf91ad26fc4144f/src/main/core-api/java/com/mysql/cj/conf/PropertyKey.java#L83) class where I found the parameters.

##### I hope I was able to help someone.