# Why do people talk about hibernate.jdbc.time_zone as a solution when Hibernate source doesn't even use it?

Tags: java, hibernate

I'm having difficulty storing timezone-agnostic `timestamp without time zone` values in PostgreSQL, using Hibernate 5.3.x, without corrupting the values with an unwanted timezone conversion. This is a well-known problem with a somewhat canonical question here: [How to store date/time and timestamps in UTC time zone with JPA and Hibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/508019/how-to-store-date-time-and-timestamps-in-utc-time-zone-with-jpa-and-hibernate) (that talks about using UTC, not "no timezone", but for my purposes, it's close enough).

The canonical solution is to use `<property name="hibernate.jdbc.time_zone" value="UTC"/>`.

This solution doesn't work for me. And when I review the code for Hibernate, I wonder how it could possibly work for anybody at all? Here's the source:

```
/*
 * Hibernate, Relational Persistence for Idiomatic Java
 *
 * License: GNU Lesser General Public License (LGPL), version 2.1 or later.
 * See the lgpl.txt file in the root directory or <http://www.gnu.org/licenses/lgpl-2.1.html>.
 */
package org.hibernate.type.descriptor.java;

import java.sql.Timestamp;
import java.time.Instant;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.ZoneId;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;

import org.hibernate.type.LocalDateTimeType;
import org.hibernate.type.descriptor.WrapperOptions;

/**
 * Java type descriptor for the LocalDateTime type.
 *
 * @author Steve Ebersole
 */
public class LocalDateTimeJavaDescriptor extends AbstractTypeDescriptor<LocalDateTime> {
    /**
     * Singleton access
     */
    public static final LocalDateTimeJavaDescriptor INSTANCE = new LocalDateTimeJavaDescriptor();

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public LocalDateTimeJavaDescriptor() {
        super( LocalDateTime.class, ImmutableMutabilityPlan.INSTANCE );
    }

    @Override
    public String toString(LocalDateTime value) {
        return LocalDateTimeType.FORMATTER.format( value );
    }

    @Override
    public LocalDateTime fromString(String string) {
        return LocalDateTime.from( LocalDateTimeType.FORMATTER.parse( string ) );
    }

    @Override
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public <X> X unwrap(LocalDateTime value, Class<X> type, WrapperOptions options) {
        if ( value == null ) {
            return null;
        }

        if ( LocalDateTime.class.isAssignableFrom( type ) ) {
            return (X) value;
        }

        if ( java.sql.Timestamp.class.isAssignableFrom( type ) ) {
            Instant instant = value.atZone( ZoneId.systemDefault() ).toInstant();
            return (X) java.sql.Timestamp.from( instant );
        }

        if ( java.sql.Date.class.isAssignableFrom( type ) ) {
            Instant instant = value.atZone( ZoneId.systemDefault() ).toInstant();
            return (X) java.sql.Date.from( instant );
        }

        if ( java.sql.Time.class.isAssignableFrom( type ) ) {
            Instant instant = value.atZone( ZoneId.systemDefault() ).toInstant();
            return (X) java.sql.Time.from( instant );
        }

        if ( java.util.Date.class.isAssignableFrom( type ) ) {
            Instant instant = value.atZone( ZoneId.systemDefault() ).toInstant();
            return (X) java.util.Date.from( instant );
        }

        if ( Calendar.class.isAssignableFrom( type ) ) {
            return (X) GregorianCalendar.from( value.atZone( ZoneId.systemDefault() ) );
        }

        if ( Long.class.isAssignableFrom( type ) ) {
            Instant instant = value.atZone( ZoneId.systemDefault() ).toInstant();
            return (X) Long.valueOf( instant.toEpochMilli() );
        }

        throw unknownUnwrap( type );
    }

    @Override
    public <X> LocalDateTime wrap(X value, WrapperOptions options) {
        if ( value == null ) {
            return null;
        }

        if ( LocalDateTime.class.isInstance( value ) ) {
            return (LocalDateTime) value;
        }

        if ( Timestamp.class.isInstance( value ) ) {
            final Timestamp ts = (Timestamp) value;
            return LocalDateTime.ofInstant( ts.toInstant(), ZoneId.systemDefault() );
        }

        if ( Long.class.isInstance( value ) ) {
            final Instant instant = Instant.ofEpochMilli( (Long) value );
            return LocalDateTime.ofInstant( instant, ZoneId.systemDefault() );
        }

        if ( Calendar.class.isInstance( value ) ) {
            final Calendar calendar = (Calendar) value;
            return LocalDateTime.ofInstant( calendar.toInstant(), calendar.getTimeZone().toZoneId() );
        }

        if ( Date.class.isInstance( value ) ) {
            final Timestamp ts = (Timestamp) value;
            final Instant instant = Instant.ofEpochMilli( ts.getTime() );
            return LocalDateTime.ofInstant( instant, ZoneId.systemDefault() );
        }

        throw unknownWrap( value.getClass() );
    }
}
```

See how many times `ZoneId.systemDefault()` is referenced? It is clearly not using any property. What am I missing here? Why does setting this property solve the problem for other people, but not me?

Comment: Same for me. I can't get that working and don't understand how other people do

Answer (score 0):

Once set, Hibernate is going to call the JDBC PreparedStatement.setTimestamp() method which takes a specific Calendar instance.
It's not done in the LocalDateTimeJavaDescriptor.