# How can we convert Timestamp datatype in Java to UTC timezone in JPA entity Java?

Tags: java, jpa, timestamp, timezone, utc

We are using PO class to represent the sql DB and using Java JPA entity.In that class, we have one column as a field `currentTime` with Timestamp datatype and `@version` annotation from JPA.

```
@Version
private Timestamp currentTime;
```

whenever the entity gets updated, currentTime is updated with the latest time.

```
currentTime = new Timestamp(0); //this will create the new timestamp with current time.
```

but it’s currently taking the time from the server. I want to convert this time to UTC format before saving it to DB.

Anyone can help how can I convert the time to UTC time?

Comment: Java's Timestamp is UTC by default, isn't it?

Comment: No, its taking the server time by default

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem when I needed to parse the time from server but I needed to convert this time to UTC format before storing this information int MySQL DB. This was my solution:

```
     Instant dateConverted = LocalDateTime
                            .parse(dateTime, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", Locale.ENGLISH))
                            .atZone(ZoneId.of("Europe/Bratislava")).toInstant();

     long epochTime = dateConverted.toEpochMilli() / 1000L;
```

Where **dateTime** is a *String* variable containing the date and time from server
And I have used *DateTimeFormatter* to format my time to appropriate format.
At the end I have added the zoneID of my timeZone and converted it to Instant

And at the end I have converted to seconds

Comment: Thanks simon. But Instant and LocalDateTime classses are not accessible

Comment: Can you tell me why are they not accessible? Do you need to do a static import for them or  your project does not allow to use these classes?

Comment: @sherinshaf Which is your Java version?

Answer (score 0):

Try below code,

```
currentTime = Timestamp.valueOf(LocalDateTime.ofInstant(Instant.now(), ZoneOffset.UTC));
```

Comment: Thanks. But Instant and LocalDateTime is not accessible from my project

Comment: Please refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/508019/how-to-store-date-time-and-timestamps-in-utc-time-zone-with-jpa-and-hibernate

Answer (score 0):

```
       SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm", Locale.getDefault());
       sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
    String localTime = sdf.format(new Date(your_time_stamp));
    Date date = new Date();
    try {
        date = sdf.parse(localTime);//get local date
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But i need to convert the timestamp with @Version annotation to UTC timezone

Comment: Please don’t teach the young ones to use the long outdated and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` class. At least not as the first option. And not without any reservation. Today we have so much better in [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API,](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) and its `DateTimeFormatter`.