# How to read "timestamp with time zone" from postgresql using hibernate Quarkus

Tags: postgresql, hibernate, quarkus

I am facing issue to display UTC date time in UI.

DB type: postgresql

DB column type: timestamp with time zone

DB column Value: 2021-11-02 22:16:16.108341-04

after read value from DB: 2021-11-02**T**22:16:16.108341-04:00

UI data: 2021-11-02T22:16:16.108341-04:00

Entity:
private OffsetDateTime createdOn;

from UI we are not able to parse UTC datetime value and display in UI. anyone able to hep me to fix date issue?

Answer (score 0):

By using `atZoneSameInstant` you could achieve what you are after, if I understood you correctly:

```
OffsetDateTime time = OffsetDateTime.parse("2021-11-02T22:16:16.108341-04:00");

ZonedDateTime timeInUTC = time.atZoneSameInstant(ZoneId.of("UTC"));

System.out.println(timeInUTC);  ///2021-11-03T02:16:16.108341Z[UTC]
```

---

```
atZoneSameInstant

public ZonedDateTime atZoneSameInstant(ZoneId zone)

Combines this date-time with a time-zone to create a ZonedDateTime ensuring that the result has the same instant.

This returns a ZonedDateTime formed from this date-time and the specified time-zone. This conversion will ignore the visible local date-time and use the underlying instant instead. This avoids any problems with local time-line gaps or overlaps. The result might have different values for fields such as hour, minute an even day.

To attempt to retain the values of the fields, use atZoneSimilarLocal(ZoneId). To use the offset as the zone ID, use toZonedDateTime().

Parameters:
    zone - the time-zone to use, not null
Returns:
    the zoned date-time formed from this date-time, not null
```

---

[image]

== Edited ==

If you wanted your database to Store the Information in (Your ZONE), but in the UI (UTC), then you need a custom method.

```
@Entity
public class YourEntity{

 private OffsetDateTime createdOn;

 public ZonedDateTime getTimeInUTC{

  return //convert createdOn;

}
```

However, why not just save the trouble and configure hibernate to store in UTC directly, if you are worried about "cost" due to conversions?:

[How to store date/time and timestamps in UTC time zone with JPA and Hibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/508019/how-to-store-date-time-and-timestamps-in-utc-time-zone-with-jpa-and-hibernate)

Comment: thanks SMA for your response. based on your response, are we have to format each row ? . it's too costly for 1000 row response. we are fetching date time from DB using hibernate. any inbuilt hibernate for this?

Comment: @SajanSoosaimicheal Kindlyl see update

Comment: thank you so much @SMA

Comment: Anytime.   Hopeit helps you